# Why doesn't this string format as currency?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

I have the following line:

```
//Send Email
clntMailBody = clntMailBody + "Order Total: " + String.Format("{0:C}", strOrderTotal + "\n");
```

Watch shows:

```
String.Format("{0:C}", strOrderTotal + "\n")    "35\n"  string
```

But it only outputs "35".  I expected "$35.00" Why is this not working as intended?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are formatting a string. Even if `strOrderTotal` is `decimal`, your `+ "\n"` forces it into a `string`.

Comment: Yes, you were all correct.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing strOrderTotal is a string? I think `{0:C}` only works for decimal or int types.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe all of these answers and no one mentioned this, change your code to

```
clntMailBody = clntMailBody + "Order Total: " + String.Format("{0:C}", strOrderTotal) + "\n";
```

And see if that solves your problem, however a better way to do it would be

```
clntMailBody = String.Format("{0}Order Total: {1:C}\n", clntMailBody, strOrderTotal);
```

It is much easier to see what is going on and removes a lot of your string concatenation.

If you are willing to do some more re-writing a even better solution is: (I made some logic up to show my example)

```
StringBuilder clntMailBody = new StringBuilder();

clntMailBody.AppendLine("Some Fixed body Text")

foreach(string lineItem in Invoice)
{
    clntMailBody.AppendLine(lineItem);
}

clntMailBody.AppendFormat("Order Total {0:C}", strOrderTotal).AppendLine();

return clntMailBody.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the declaration of `strOrderTotal` but by it's name I assuming it's already  a `string`. As it's already a string the formatting won't work.

If you want the formatting to work you'll need to pass the order total in as a number - preferably a `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a string.

Trying to format a string returns... the string.

You need a numeric value in order to get it formatted as currency.

You will see that the `C` format specifier is defined in the [Standard **Numeric** Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) page on MSDN. Numeric, not "strings".

Answer (score 2):

I presume that strOrderTotal is string ? It had to be decimal, or double etc

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that `strOrderTotal` is a string. You should use a numeric type, like double or Decimal.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like (based on the variable name `strOrderTotal`) that your total is already a string.  The "C" format specifier converts a number to currency format, not something that's already a string.

Therefore you need to either manually format your string as currency or apply the currency format when the order total is originally converted to a string (when it's stored in `strOrderTotal`).

Answer (score 1):

If strOrderTotal is a string you can use this code to format it for currency

```
clntMailBody = clntMailBody + "Order Total: " + String.Format("{0:C}", decimal.Parse(strOrderTotal) + "\n");
```

Comment: No. You cannot convert a string to a decimal by a cast.

Comment: `decimal.Parse(string)` would work, but casting a decimal to a string will not.

Answer (score 0):

To display a string in the currency format:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("Your total amount is ");
sb.AppendFormat("{0:C} ", 25 );
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Output:

> Your total amount is $25.00